# how to get mypy to globally ignore missing imports?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a number of files that import other untyped libraries.

I've added this to `mypy.ini` eg:

```
[coloredlogs]
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

So maybe that works to NOT check the library itself? eg in a `/venv` but still in every.single.place a library is imported I get these warnings.

The only way i can get the ignore working is adding annotation on every.single.import

`import coloredlogs  # type: ignore`

refs: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your configuration syntax is wrong. The [example in the docs you've linked](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-type-hints-for-third-party-library) is

```
[mypy-foobar.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

so you'll want

```
[mypy-coloredlogs.*]
ignore_missing_imports = True
```

Comment: nice, thanks! I guess I only have to set this stuff up once...